# How to write a file indexing software in java?

Tags: java, file, filesystems

I want to write a software to search my hard disk for pdf files and index them in a library by analysing the content .

Please help me how to achieve it using Java platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html), it is THE indexing and searching framework in Java.

For indexing PDF documents, you can use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) that integrates nicely with Lucene.

Comment: Thanks . But what if i want to write my own libraries. What approach should i use ?

Answer (score 1):

May be a simpler solution for PDF and other document files take a look at [Tika](http://tika.apache.org).

Answer (score 0):

This open source project might be a start for you. It uses Apache Lucene and PDFBox:

- https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pdfindexer

Comment: Version 0.0.6 is available as of today